# Advice on splitting up very broad tags

Tags: discussion, tags

On the SE I moderate, we have a few tags that are on a very large number of questions, specifically six tags are on ~7.5–12.5% of the 10,000+ questions.

These tags are on a broad range of questions that cover large parts of the topics discussed on the site, and do not work well to represent and confine topics.
I have proposed to deprecate and replace these tags with tags that encompass narrower subtopics.

> *Example:* If the delinquent tag was [food](/questions/tagged/food), I am suggesting to retag to [snacks](/questions/tagged/snacks), [desserts](/questions/tagged/desserts), [appetizers](/questions/tagged/appetizers), [main-dishes](/questions/tagged/main-dishes), [side-dishes](/questions/tagged/side-dishes)…

This turns out to be a lot of work, especially since there are few people coming to aid.

- Has someone tried something similar and can report on the results? (Is it worth it?)
- Are there best practices, on how to engage the community in this sort of endeavours?
- Is there a way to retag questions that have a combination of **two tags**? E.g. [food](/questions/tagged/food)+[between-meals](/questions/tagged/between-meals) → [snacks](/questions/tagged/snacks).
- Is this a fool's errand/over-moderation?

---

Obligatory links to the actual meta-posts:

- [Mining is on more than 10% of the questions, how can we structure that content better?](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/719/5406)
- [The Great Retag of [mining]](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/734/5406)

Comment: To be honest... I'm not certain that 12%'s all that bad... I know some sites with 25-30% usage of a single tag... and there's simply no way to break it up, short of banning the question type (ID questions on Movies.SE and SFF.SE)... Realistically, mining is a major part of Bitcoin. (Admittedly, I don't know much about cryptocurrencies, though)

Comment: @Catija: Thanks for your interest. I'm not quite sure what to take from your comment. Mostly, it seems to question the usefulness of my proposal. As you said, mining is indeed a major part of Bitcoin, but that's exactly the issue: "mining" is linked to many activities in Bitcoin and thus doesn't serve well to confine a topic. (I.e. it adds little information about the question to add it, doesn't serve for ignoring or following, is somewhat ambiguous,…) Hence my proposal of the split. It seems to me that ID questions are a very special case that doesn't compare to mining well.